# Canonical C++ way to control function return type with sensible default

Tags: c++

What is the canonical way to control the return type of a function based on an input type with a sensible default?

e.g.

```
// by default want R = decltype(container)::value_type

template<typename R>
R func(const auto& container)
{
    R result{};
    // some calculations using container
    return result;
}
```

The usage would be:

```
std::vector<int> ct{};

func(ct);           // default result -> int
func<double>(ct);   // custom call -> double
```

I could drop the use of auto and use another template argument:

```
template<typename C, typename R = C::value_type>
R func(const C& container)
{
    R result{};
    // some calculations using container
    return result;
}
```

But then usage for the control case is less than ideal:

```
func<std::vector<int>, double>(ct); // custom call -> double
```

I could reorder the template arguments:

```
template<typename R, typename C>
R func(const C& container)
{
    R result{};
    // some calculations using container
    return result;
}
```

But then I lose my default behaviour:

```
func(ct);        // no longer works
func<int>(ct);   // required <int>
```

Comment: This looks like a job for template specialization.

Comment: One possibility is you define a type like `struct use_default_type {};` and then you use some more templates to pick the correct type if the type is use_default_type

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about canonical C++, but this works:

```cpp
template<typename R=void>
auto func(const auto& container)
{
    using Out = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_same_v<R, void>,
        typename std::decay_t<decltype(container)>::value_type,
        R>;
         
    Out result{};
    // some calculations using container
    return result;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TfPxcf8Mh)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine function template overloading with SFINAE to handle both cases:

```cpp
template<typename C, typename R = typename C::value_type>
R func(C const& container) {
    R result{};
    // some calculations using container
    return result;
}

template<typename R, typename C>
R func(C const& container) {
    return func<C, R>(container);
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bPYGG79Kc)

Answer (score 1):

You could work around the problem by using `auto` as the return type.  Something like

```
// by default want R = decltype(container)::value_type

template<typename R = void>
auto func(const auto& container)
{
    // if R is void use value_type otherwise use R
    using RetType = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<R, void>, typename std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(container)>::value_type, R>;
    RetType result{};
    // some calculations using container
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to return something you can use `void` as sentinel and defer deduction of the return type to the body of the function:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,typename Select>
struct select_default_or_T{
    using type = std::conditional_t< std::is_same_v<void,Select> , typename T::value_type,Select>::type;
};


template<typename R = void>
auto func(const auto& container)
{
    using R = typename select_default_or_T<decltype(container),R>::type;
    R result{};
    // some calculations using container
    return result;
}
```

Well, the name of the traits needs a fix, but I think you get the idea.